# Jquery scroll event return to original

Tags: jquery

```
$(document).scroll(function(){
    $("#linkd").css("opacity", "0.1");         
});
```

It changes the opacity when I scroll but how do I make it go back to its original opacity when user stops scrolling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you develop a mobile page you can use jQuery mobile library with build in 
events : scrollstart and scrollstop, and save the original opacity in the window.opacity location for later restore.

```js
window.opacity = 1;

$(document).on("scrollstart", function(){
  $('#output').html("scrolling");
  window.opacity = $("#linkd").css("opacity");
  $("#linkd").css("opacity", "0.1"); 
});
      
$(document).on("scrollstop",function(){
  $("#linkd").css("opacity", window.opacity);
  $('#output').html("stopped");
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  line-height: 1.5;
}
#output {
  width: 100%;
  height: 2em;
  background: #eee;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 2;
}

#linkd {
  margin: 3.5em auto 2em auto;
  max-width: 40em;
}
```

```html
<!-- Include the jQuery library -->
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>

<!-- Include the jQuery Mobile library -->
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>

<div id="output"></div>
    <div id="linkd">
      
      <p>Aenean eu leo quam. Pellentesque ornare sem lacinia quam venenatis vestibulum. Nullam quis risus eget urna mollis ornare vel eu leo. Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit. Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue. Curabitur blandit tempus porttitor. Morbi leo risus, porta ac consectetur ac, vestibulum at eros.</p>
      
      <p>Morbi leo risus, porta ac consectetur ac, vestibulum at eros. Aenean lacinia bibendum nulla sed consectetur. Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
      
      <p>Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit sit amet non magna. Donec sed odio dui. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Morbi leo risus, porta ac consectetur ac, vestibulum at eros.</p>
      <p>Morbi leo risus, porta ac consectetur ac, vestibulum at eros. Donec ullamcorper nulla non metus auctor fringilla. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Curabitur blandit tempus porttitor. Aenean eu leo quam. Pellentesque ornare sem lacinia quam venenatis vestibulum.</p>
      
      <p>Aenean eu leo quam. Pellentesque ornare sem lacinia quam venenatis vestibulum. Nullam quis risus eget urna mollis ornare vel eu leo. Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit. Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue. Curabitur blandit tempus porttitor. Morbi leo risus, porta ac consectetur ac, vestibulum at eros.</p>
      
      <p>Morbi leo risus, porta ac consectetur ac, vestibulum at eros. Aenean lacinia bibendum nulla sed consectetur. Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
      
      <p>Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit sit amet non magna. Donec sed odio dui. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Morbi leo risus, porta ac consectetur ac, vestibulum at eros.</p>
      <p>Morbi leo risus, porta ac consectetur ac, vestibulum at eros. Donec ullamcorper nulla non metus auctor fringilla. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Curabitur blandit tempus porttitor. Aenean eu leo quam. Pellentesque ornare sem lacinia quam venenatis vestibulum.</p>
      
      <p>Aenean eu leo quam. Pellentesque ornare sem lacinia quam venenatis vestibulum. Nullam quis risus eget urna mollis ornare vel eu leo. Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit. Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue. Curabitur blandit tempus porttitor. Morbi leo risus, porta ac consectetur ac, vestibulum at eros.</p>
      
      <p>Morbi leo risus, porta ac consectetur ac, vestibulum at eros. Aenean lacinia bibendum nulla sed consectetur. Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
      
      <p>Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit sit amet non magna. Donec sed odio dui. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Morbi leo risus, porta ac consectetur ac, vestibulum at eros.</p>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

With add a timeout you can detect that when user stops scrolling.
You have to set a timeout and clear that while scroll event is working.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    $("#linkd").css("opacity", "0.1");
    //clear timeout on scrolling
    clearTimeout(function(){scrollTimer()});
    //start timeout when scrolling is finished
    var scrollTimer = setTimeout(function() {
        $("#linkd").css("opacity", "1");    
    }, 1000);
});
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/94d81wo4/

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery to make the content fade in and fade out depending on your position on the screen. For more information check out this link: http://api.jquery.com/fadein/

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
       if($(window).scrollTop()<10){
             $("#linkd").fadeOut("fast");
       } else {
            $("#linkd").fadeIn("fast");
       }
    });​
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Answer (score 0):

This help you :

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(window).scroll(function(){

        $("#linkd").css({opacity:0.1}); 

        clearTimeout($.data(this,"timer"));

        $.data(this, 'timer', setTimeout(function() {

            $("#linkd").css({opacity:1});

            }, 500));
    })
})
```